# Can't find / download AppCompat-v7:23.1.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat

## What's the matter:

I had many problems with "appcompat-v7 23.1.1 not found". None of many solutions worked. After hours of thinking and searching for the answer I've encountered a strange problem.
 I **have got** Android Support Library 23.1.1 Installed. All features - **except** AppCompat-v7 - are installed. 
 Main question is: *How to force Android SDK Manager to download AppCompat 23.1.1?*

## Things I did:

- Reinstalled **Android Support Library** - didn't work
- Ran Android SDK Manager as an **Administrator**  - didn't work
- Deleted whole ~\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support folder & installed Android Support Library again - didn't work
- Finally I installed a new instance of Android SDK, downloaded Android Support Library and copied it whole to the old repo.

## Yay! It worked, but...

... but it makes no sense in the long run. Every library update will cause same problem. Is there any way to download that appCompat, or should I simply delete whole SDK and spend like 3hours to install it all over again?

Regards,
pawpaw

## EDIT - gradle builder log (logcat says nothing) :

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>        Required by:
>            MyApp:app:unspecified
>
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Android/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
>        Required by:
>            MyApp:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.1.1

Comment: Can you post the logcat report?

Comment: sure, here you go @harshit-gupta

Comment: hav you tried to update the `android sdk tools` package from the sdk manager? after updating that restart the sdk manager and try updating the support repository (android sdk tools revision should be 24.4.1 as of now)

Comment: @Dodge yup, have 24.4.1 version :(

Comment: Update Android Support repository in SDK Manager.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have my whole SDK updated. :( Maybe it is something wrong with the whole SDK launcher? IDK... I reinstalled SDK. That was the best I could do